# How to merge two datasets that have different column names in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 datasets

x_data has 130 variables (columns)

y_data has 126 variables (columns)

Both data sets have information I need but after doing

```
intersect(names(x_data), names(y_data))
```

Only 19 columns actually match.

For example, x_data has the column "Frist Name" while the column also exists in y_data but as "FirstName".

There are multiple examples of this but there also may be columns that exists in 1 dataframe but not the other.

If there a fast way for me go edit these columns so they can have the same name?

My end goal is to rbind() to merge these datasets vertically.

Comment: You can try stripping out spaces {gsub()} and making the names all lowercase {tolower()}.  Then, setting the names to the new ones using {names ()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`colnames`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html) function in R to set column names for a dataframe `df` like this:

```rb
colnames(df) <- c("Column1","Column2",..........,"ColumnN")
```